# Assign DataSet Table to a variable of Type Control

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I have lots of research on this but getting nothing

I have many ComboBox Controls within a form, and I need to fill them with data stored in DataSet Table as bellow:

```
foreach (Control ctrl in this.Controls)
{
     if (ctrl.GetType() == typeof(ComboBox))
     {
        clsMasterFunc.TableName = ctrl.Text;
        dsMasterList = clsMasterFunc.select();

        ctrl.DataSource = dsMasterList.Tables[0];
     }
}
```

But, I am getting the following error

```
'System.Windows.Forms.Control' does not contain a definition for 'DataSource' and no extension method 'DataSource' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.Control' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

How Can I use DataSource properties in this case ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ctrl` is variable of type `Control` and hence `DataSource` property is not available. `DataSource` property is available in `ComboBox`. Cast `ctrl` to `ComboBox` like this

```
((ComboBox)ctrl).DataSource = dsMasterList.Tables[0];
```

So your code becomes

```
foreach (Control ctrl in this.Controls)
{
     if (ctrl.GetType() == typeof(ComboBox))
     {
        clsMasterFunc.TableName = ctrl.Text;
        dsMasterList = clsMasterFunc.select();

        ((ComboBox)ctrl).DataSource = dsMasterList.Tables[0];
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that ctrl is of type Control in that iteration. Yeah, it is typeof(Combobox) but you are not casting it to the proper control.

You can do it in several ways:

Try using ofType:

```
  this.Controls.OfType<ComboBox>().ToList().ForEach(c =>
  {
      c.DataSource = dsMasterList.Tables[0];
   });
```

It will enter the lambda expression as combobox, so no cast needed using OfType.

You can also cast your controls to Combobox to have the DataSource Property available:

```
 ComboBox combo = (ComboBox) ctrl;
 combo.DataSource =  dsMasterList.Tables[0];
```

This is one single line:

```
 ((ComboBox)ctrl).DataSource = dsMasterList.Tables[0];
```